# What is the origin of move semantics in C++?

Tags: c++, history, move-semantics

I am wondering what is the origin of [move semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors) in C++? In particular was it invented specifically for this language or there was something similar in other language(s)? In the latter case could you give some references.

Comment: Perhaps one of the most compelling reasons for move semantics in C++11 is the lack of move semantics in C++03, which clearly manifested in the hacked-up implementation of `auto_ptr`. It was clear that there was something one *wanted* to do but couldn't do cleanly because of lack of language support.

Comment: move semantics has been around as long as people have been programming, but it was all manual. The introduction of move semantics as a language feature is about how to encode the idea of 'moveability' into the type system so that the compiler can decide when to 'move' things, and how user defined types can declare what it means for them to be moved. Move semantics in C++ is a product of C++'s emphasis on encoding information in the type system. I'm not aware of earlier languages that put quite the same emphasis on the type system as C++.

Comment: @bames53: That might have been great as an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just wasn't confident enough in my knowledge of historic languages. The fact that the proposal you linked in your answer to doesn't acknowledge previous languages seems like pretty good evidence though, so I voted for your answer :)

Comment: @bames53: TBH if you'd written your first comment as an answer, and I were the OP, I'd have accepted it :

Comment: The C++ fanbois got annoyed at the constant sniping at their beloved language re. excess value copying, so they invented semantics to avoid some of the copying and called it 'move'.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any kind of specific ancestor to the concept. The origin of C++'s move semantics, as noted in [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Introduction), was discussion in newsgroups:

> Move semantics in various forms has been discussed in C++ forums (most
>   notably comp.lang.c++.moderated) for years.

To my mind, they are tightly coupled with C++'s notion of lvalues and rvalues which, if I'm not mistaken, is purely a C++ concept. A language that doesn't have lvalues, rvalues and their new C++11 friends doesn't need move semantics in the way that C++ implements them.

More generally, though, the concept of moving stuff around rather than copying is just a fundamental concept. Whenever you write a linked list and you "swap elements" by actually just swapping pointers to them, you're doing a "move". Basically.

Comment: lvalue and rvalue concepts came from C, though I think they only used the term lvalue and referred to rvalues as 'not an lvalue'.

Comment: The fact that values were moved does not mean that the concept of moving values was understood. People do think about swap as copy-copy-copy.

Comment: @Elazar: Speak for yourself. Most people have had this right in their minds for decades, I can assure you!

Comment: Now you're the one speaking for "most people" :) People may know what they want to do, but in translating that thought to code, they may lose the abstract "move" part. What I mean is, naming this notion (in the language) is important, even if the name existed outside the language. And even if move was not baked into the language, the name should have been introduced. Somewhat like concepts.

Comment: @Elazar: There is more than sufficient evidence that the notion of moving rather than copying data is entirely commonplace. Just look at all the projects using `memmove` mate!

Comment: `memmove` is just "copy and don't do bad things if it overlaps". Possibly useful for copying one array element to all the cells in the array; no real "move" there. `memory move` is rather meaningless, in the C++-meaning for `move`.

Comment: @Elazar: Okay `memmove` was a terrible example. But I stand by my claims. Just look at all the projects using linked lists!

Comment: Again, the fact that people do something that fit the word `move` does not mean they actually realize this fact.

Comment: @Elazar: Hey, bartender! I'll have whatever he's having!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you're gettin' 'em in, I'll have a double.

Answer (score 1):

You can read ["A Proposal to Add Move Semantics Support to the C++ Language"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm) to get more information on the motivation behind the concept, as well as why this needs to have direct language support rather than being implemented using library facilities.